# SQL вывести сущности МНОГИЕ КО МНОГИМ по условию

Tags: mysql, join, sql

Есть 2 таблицы:

**partner** (партнёры)

```
id    | name
-----------------
1     | partner_1
2     | partner_2
3     | partner_3
4     | partner_4
```

**contract** (договоры)

```
id    | name        | is_active
-------------------------------
1     | contract_1  | 1
2     | contract_2  | 0
3     | contract_3  | 1
4     | contract_4  | 0
5     | contract_5  | 0
```

Есть третья таблица, которая связывает предыдущие 2 таблицы с соотношением МНОГИЕ КО МНОГИМ

**partner_contract**

```
partner_id | contract_id
------------------------
1          | 1
1          | 2
2          | 3
2          | 2
2          | 4
3          | 5
```

К каждому партнёру может быть привязано несколько договоров, среди которых **ТОЛЬКО ОДИН** может быть активным и несколько неактивных.
Так же, к партнёру может быть вообще не привязан ни один договор.

Нужно написать такой запрос, который выводит всех партнёров вместе с активным договором. Если активного договора нет, то соответственно вывести NULL.

```
partner_id | partner_name | contract_name
-----------------------------------------
1          | partner_1    | contract_1
2          | partner_2    | contract_3
3          | partner_3    | NULL
4          | partner_4    | NULL
```

Я нашел решение, но оно не кажется мне идеальным.

```
SELECT
    p.id AS partner_id,
    p.name AS partner_name,
    active_contract.name AS contract_name
FROM partner p
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM contract c
    LEFT JOIN partner_contract pc on pc.contract_id = c.id
    WHERE c.is_active = 1
) active_contract
ON active_contract.partner_id = p.id
```

**Есть ли более элегантное решение?**

Comment: нормальное решение, только * замените на необходимые вам поля (`pc.partner_id, c.name`).

Answer (score 3):

Пригодился редкий камушек RIGHT JOIN :)

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`name`, c.`name` AS `contract_name`
FROM
  `partner_contract` AS pc INNER JOIN
  `contract`         AS c ON c.`id` = pc.`contract_id` AND c.`is_active` = 1 RIGHT JOIN
  `partner`          AS p ON p.`id` = pc.`partner_id`
```

результат

```
id  name    name
1   partner_1   contract_1
2   partner_2   contract_3
3   partner_3   (null)
4   partner_4   (null)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27a4e/1

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить условие c.is_active=1 прямо в секцию ON. Попробуйте так

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.contract_name
FROM partner p
LEFT JOIN partner_contract p2c 
    ON p.id = p2c.partner_id
LEFT JOIN contract c
    ON p2c.contract_id = c.id AND c.is_active=1
```

Comment: получится больше строк, чем надо )))

Comment: artoodetoo, да, точно))) Надо порядком джоинов разрулить.